# XeLaTeX and stmaryrd

Tags: math-mode, xetex, mathspec, alphabet

I'm using XeLaTeX and Minion Pro together with the `\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}` but I need the \llbracket and \rrbracket command from `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` package. Unfortunately, as such, I get a "Too many math alphabets" error message. As a solution, I can redefine my own \llbracket and \rrbracket with existing [, ] and | symbols or try to extract the definition of the \rrbracket and \llbracket commands from stmaryrd as follows (taken from stmaryrd.sty):

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter\llbracket{\mathopen}{stmry}{"4A}{stmry}{"71}
\DeclareMathDelimiter\rrbracket{\mathclose}{stmry}{"4B}{stmry}{"79}
```

would this work? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating, I could find the equivalent commands from `MnSymbol`, namely `\lsem` and `\rsem`. I'm still interested in a method detailing how to extract a single command from a package. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This code from unicode-math supposedly removes the 16-family limit for maths fonts. It might help here.

```
\def\new@mathgroup{\alloc@8\mathgroup\chardef\@cclvi}
\let\newfam\new@mathgroup
```

Comment: I'll try this for another problem that I met with the \mathfrak command still yielding the "Too many math alphabets" error message. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I use your code correctly but I still get the "too many math alphabets" error message. If I use `\usepackage{stmaryrd}`, the \mathcal command yield the error message, I'm not quite sure why. This limitation is very annoying.

Comment: @pluton The limitation should have been raised with TeX Live 2012. Can you try?

Comment: @egreg ok, I'll try to remember the problem but it may take some time.

Answer (score 1):

I am two years late, but you can actually write:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{stmry}{U}{stmry}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{stmry}{bold}{U}{stmry}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter\llbracket{\mathopen}{stmry}{"4A}{stmry}{"71}
\DeclareMathDelimiter\rrbracket{\mathclose}{stmry}{"4B}{stmry}{"79}
```

With the above, you don't actually need any `\usepackage` options, just required that `stmaryrd` is installed.

Comment: What's the difference with respect to what the OP was already been doing? It's obvious from the `\DeclareMathDelimiter` lines that pluton was already specifying `\DeclareSymbolFont{stmry}{U}{stmry}{m}{n}` or they wouldn't have worked. The problem was quite different, and due to the limitation to 16 math families. Since the release of TeX Live 2012 the limitation does not exist any more for XeLaTeX and Will Robertson's answer should work.

Comment: Missing that crucial statement will result in a file that will not compile. Perhaps I did not word my answer more carefully to point that out. It may be clear to TeX experts but not average users like me. I certainly did not know I need the line `\DeclareSymbolFont{stmry}{U}{stmry}{m}{n}`, I had to hunt for the source code and just by luck, saw that line. I hope this will help someone else.

Comment: One can argue from the question that the standards of this site have evolved: the same question asked now would have one or more comments pledging for a MWE. :)

Comment: If one uses [egreg's tactic using Pisymbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14406/3627), then it's not necessary to include `\DeclareSymbolFont`.