# fake math alphabet

Tags: math-mode, xetex, alphabet

in order to go over the "too many alphabets" usual error, I am creating fake math commands somehow.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[top=3.2cm,bottom=3.2cm,left=3.3cm,right=3.3cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{esvect}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\vv}
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Uppercase=Regular,Lowercase=Italic]{Minion Pro}

% correct commands yielding the math alphabet error messages when uncommented
\setmathrm{Minion Pro} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\dive}{div}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}=\cos \pi\quad\vec{e}=3\vec{\dive}(u)\mathfrak{B}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This code as such will not compile. As a work-around, when the two lines defining the Math Alphabet of the document are replaced (you have to comment them) by :

```
% fake cosinus and divergence commands to get similar results without the error message
\renewcommand{\cos}{\text{cos}\,}
\newcommand{\dive}{\text{div}\,}
```

the code will compile with very similar results: what is wrong then, with this trick?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the math alphabets MnSymbol and Minin Pro, but look here [“Too many math alphabets” error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3676/too-many-math-alphabets-error). They don't use XeTeX but apparently it has something to do with MnSymbol. If you replace

```
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
```

by

```
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
```

your example compiles without problems. It may not be the right font though...

But concerning the *wrong* of the trick: If your use this construction inside of some environment that changes the text font, this won't work. Inside a theorem the text will be italic and so will your `\text{cos}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\itshape
\[\cos \neq \text{cos}\]
\end{document}
```

Also, if you decide at a later point to change fonts and not use the same for text and math, you will probably see that the `cos` will be in the text font and therefore somewhat out of place in the middle of the formula.

Comment: yes for the italic example. I'm not using such environments, so it should not be a problem but you are correct.

Comment: Well, you never know where you or someone else uses it again. It's just no good practise. And for the math alphabets - your are not the first, see above.

Comment: yes, I know it is not good practice and I know that I am not the first. I was just experimenting a possible trick.

Comment: Also, there are some implications on spacing around the MathOperator, especially in conjunction with parentheses around the following argument.

Comment: Removing the MnSymbol option could be a solution. I am not using so many items of the list.