# Is there a way to do an "upside down" \widehat?

Tags: symbols, accents

I've come across this in a book I'm looking through, but I can't find the code for it. I want it to look exactly like the `\widehat` and go above text like `\widehat` does...I just want it to be (vertically) flipped!

Comment: ...and you're not referring to `\v{a}`, right?

Comment: @Werner: That's correct. That's the shape I want, but it needs to be able to work in math mode, and it needs to be able to change size depending on how many characters show up inside the {}.

Comment: See [*Is there a \widecheck like \widehat?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249352/2930) for definitions that *avoid* using [`mathabx`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44235/is-there-a-way-to-do-an-upside-down-widehat), which is [**incompatible with `amssymb`**](https://www.google.com/search?q=amssymb+mathabx).

Comment: Remark: mathabx has some issues with nesting accents → https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/665667/250119

Answer (score 45):

The symbol you are looking for is `widecheck` and can be found in the [`mathabx`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathabx) font package. Please consult pages 10 and 16 of the [`mathabx` user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mathabx/mathtest.pdf). The syntax is `\widecheck{xyz}`.

Here is a minimum working example to demonstrate:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$\widecheck{\theta\tilde\theta} + \widecheck{\phi^2-\rho}$
\end{document}
```

The second example compares the behavior of `\hat`, `\widehat`, `\check`, and `\widecheck`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
& \textbf{narrow} & \textbf{wide} \\
\hline
\textbf{hat} & $\hat{I}+\hat{II}+\hat{III}+\hat{IIII}$ & $\widehat{I}+\widehat{II}+\widehat{III}+\widehat{IIII}$\\
\hline
\textbf{check} & $\check{I}+\check{II}+\check{III}+\check{IIII}$ & $\widecheck{I}+\widecheck{II}+\widecheck{III}+\widecheck{IIII}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

To install the `mathabx` font package, one of the following may work:

1. If you are using Debian/Ubuntu, simply run `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra texlive-fonts-extra-doc`.
2. If you have a new version of TexLive, then something like `sudo tlmgr update --self` followed by `tlmgr install mathabx` should work (I haven't tested this because I do not have `tlmgr`).

Comment: +1 very elaborate answer. I think that "`widecheck`" would have been sufficient:o)

Comment: @user001 - WOW. What a thorough and helpful response. Thanks so much; that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: \usepackage{mathabx} makes certain symbols look weird, not standard (e.g. \infty becomes a rotated unsymmetric number 8; \in has three different length lines etc).

Answer (score 39):

while the answer by @user001 is correct in that `\widecheck` is supported by the `mathabx` fonts and package, that package/font collection also changes the shapes of a lot of (most) other symbols.  if you want to avoid such "extra" changes, you can load just the symbol(s) you want as shown in this example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\nofiles
\usepackage{verbatim}

%% code from mathabx.sty and mathabx.dcl
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widecheck}{0}{mathx}{"71}
\DeclareMathAccent{\wideparen}{0}{mathx}{"75}

\def\cs#1{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}

\begin{document}

A wide check should match a wide hat, but inverted.  Observe that
the forms provided have a maximum width.  Some other wide accents
in \verb|mathx| aren't available otherwise.
\begin{align*}
\cs{widehat}:\quad & \widehat{A}\quad\widehat{AB}\quad
   \widehat{ABC}\quad\widehat{ABCD}\quad\widehat{ABCDE}\\
\cs{widecheck}:\quad & \widecheck{A}\quad\widecheck{AB}\quad
   \widecheck{ABC}\quad\widecheck{ABCD}\quad\widecheck{ABCDE}\\
\cs{wideparen}:\quad & \wideparen{A}\quad\wideparen{AB}\quad
   \wideparen{ABC}\quad\wideparen{ABCD}\quad\wideparen{ABCDE}
\end{align*}

\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\verbatiminput{\jobname.tex}
\end{document}
```

note: this demonstration was created long ago for use in ams publications, hence the extra unrelated code; however, the technique of using the `verbatim` package to generate a list of the example file in the output, using `\verbatiminput`, has proved very useful here, and may do so for others, so i haven't removed it.

Comment: Works but add an error only with the `beamer` class in my case: `Too many math alphabets used in version normal.`

It seems like there is a limitation of 16 math alphabets (see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3677/19042)).

Answer (score 9):

### Code

I copied the following code from someone a long time ago.  I don't understand it, but it also seems to produce wide checks in math mode.

```
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\widecheck[1]{{\mathpalette\@widecheck{#1}}}
\def\@widecheck#1#2{%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{\m@th$#1#2$}%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{\m@th$#1%
       \widehat{%
          \vrule\@width\z@\@height\ht\z@
          \vrule\@height\z@\@width\wd\z@}$}%
    \dp\tw@-\ht\z@
    \@tempdima\ht\z@ \advance\@tempdima2\ht\tw@ \divide\@tempdima\thr@@
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{%
       \raise\@tempdima\hbox{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\lower\@tempdima\box
\tw@}}}%
    {\ooalign{\box\tw@ \cr \box\z@}}}
\makeatother
```

### Output and comparison

Here is the output with different font sizes and a comparison with the `\widecheck{}` command from the `mathabx` package:

[image: widecheck output and comparison]

Comment: I dont understand it either, so it must be good

Comment: It seems that only `\scalebox` is used from the `mathtools` package, and it is actually from the `graphicx` package.

Comment: Unfortunately, exponents end up in the wrong place with this code. Compare `\widecheck{y}^2` with this code and mathabx...

Comment: @Dominique Good point!