# Is there a \widecheck like \widehat?

Tags: fonts, symbols

The question *"[Is there a way to do an "upside down" \widehat?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44235/is-there-a-way-to-do-an-upside-down-widehat)"* indicates that `\widecheck` is available in the [`mathabx`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44235/is-there-a-way-to-do-an-upside-down-widehat) package, but unfortunately, that package also changes the font style.

Can we define `\widecheck` by ourselves?

Comment: Are you on `beamer`? If not, please use this answer of the post you have linked to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44277 . Why have you tagged [tag:latex3e]?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font for how to import just a single glyph from `mathabx`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- the answers in the two referenced questions are not materially different, although the one you reference is a bit more specific about why a font family must be "wasted".

Answer (score 10):

You can import just `\widecheck`, but it makes sense to also import `\widehat`, to get similar symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<-> mathx10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widehat}{0}{mathx}{"70}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widecheck}{0}{mathx}{"71}

\begin{document}

$\widehat{abc}+\widecheck{abc}$

$\widehat{abcde}+\widecheck{abcde}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I did not know if it would be this easy, but it turned out so.  I took my revised answer at [Really wide hat symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol/101136#101136) for `\reallywidehat` and made two simple changes:

1. I changed all occurences of "hat" to "check"
2. I changed the final `\stackon` argument from `\tmpbox` to `\scalebox{-1}{\tmpbox}`.

That was it.  Here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\reallywidecheck[1]{%
\savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
  \scaleto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
    {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
  }{\textheight}% 
}{0.5ex}}%
\stackon[1pt]{#1}{\scalebox{-1}{\tmpbox}}%
}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

$\reallywidecheck{zbcdefghijklm}$

$\reallywidecheck{zbcdefghijk}$

$\reallywidecheck{zbcdefghi}$

$\reallywidecheck{zbcdefg}$

$\reallywidecheck{zbcde}$

$\reallywidecheck{zbc}$

$\reallywidecheck{zb}$

$x\cdot\reallywidecheck{a_1+a_2}\cdot y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Best of all, it avoids the use of `mathabx`, which resets a lot of math symbols.

Comment: I've copied/pasted your code, and everything seems to be working nicely for the most part, but when I try to typeset and expression like "\reallywidehat{\chi}" it gives me an error that I'm missing a $. It only seems to work with Roman letters. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: @Patch When I take my above code and add the line, `$\reallywidecheck{\chi}$`, it works just fine.  Remember, `\chi` is a math symbol and has to be invoked in math mode.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't working for me even in the dollar signs. I can't figure it out. I ended up just copy/pasting the segment of "widecheck" code directly from mathabx. I didn't need a "really" wide one after all.

Comment: @Patch Make sure your package is up to date: `scalerel 2016/12/29 v1.8`

Answer (score 4):

[pdfMsym](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfmsym) provides wide accents (which can stretch arbitrarily), including `\varwidecheck` which may suit your needs:

```latex
\input pdfmsym
\pdfmsymsetscalefactor{10}

\begin{gather*}
\varwidecheck{abcdefgijk} \\
\varwidecheck{abcdefg} \\
\varwidecheck{abc}
\end{gather*}
```

[image: varwidecheck demo]

pdfMsym defines a macro `\accent@skew` which sets the skew of the accent from the left side of the material it is placed over, if you don't like this you can `\def\accent@skew{0}`. You can similarly play with `\accent@raise` (which sets the vertical difference between the accent and the material).