# Compiling on the laptop vs on Overleaf

Tags: pdftex, overleaf

For some reason, the minimal working example below, compiled on TexMaker (and also on TexShop) with TeX distribution 2022 does not render as when I compile it on Overleaf, namely I get an extra space on the last line as shown on the picture on the left:

[image: texmaker]  [image: overleaf]

I do not understand why this happens. Deleting some of the (useless) packages removes this extra space, but still I would like to undestand why this strange behavior occurs.
Does anyone get the same result on their laptop as mine?

After the code below, there is the result of the "diff" command applied to the two log files, and also the full log file from my laptop version.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}%mathfrak
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{esvect}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{wncy}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wncy}{m}{n}{<->wncyr10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mcy}{U}{wncy}{m}{n}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44235/
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

%Music notes
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows3}{LS2}{stixtt}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$\mathds{1} \mathfrak{f}$
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
$$(P)$$ 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
\end{document}
```

Result of "diff" between the two log files:

```
< This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.8.9)  1 NOV 2022 13:22
---
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.9.2)  1 NOV 2022 14:21
3c3
<  \write18 enabled.
---
>  restricted \write18 enabled.
5,8c5,9
< **main.tex
< (./main.tex
< LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
< L3 programming layer <2022-08-05> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
---
> **mainfile.tex
> (./mainfile.tex
> LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
> L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
59c60
< File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-08-05 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
---
> File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-02-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
61,63c62,65
< \l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
< ) (./output.aux)
< \openout1 = `output.aux'.
---
> \l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
> )
> (./mainfile.aux)
> \openout1 = `mainfile.aux'.
124c126,127
< $\U/dsrom/m/n/10 1\U/euf/m/n/10 f$ \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text Text-
---
> $\U/dsrom/m/n/10 1\U/euf/m/n/10 f$ \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Tex
> t-Text-Text Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text Text-
130c133,134
< {/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./output.aux) ) 
---
> {/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
> (./mainfile.aux) ) 
132,135c136,139
<  1494 strings out of 477678
<  23551 string characters out of 5829488
<  309332 words of memory out of 5000000
<  20286 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
---
>  1471 strings out of 478268
>  22894 string characters out of 5846348
>  298945 words of memory out of 5000000
>  19674 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
138,140c142,148
<  41i,5n,51p,174b,107s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
< </usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/doublestroke/dsrom10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/euler/eufm10.pfb>
< Output written on output.pdf (1 page, 25795 bytes).
---
>  41i,5n,51p,178b,107s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
> </usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
> ts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
> s/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/doublestr
> oke/dsrom10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
> /euler/eufm10.pfb>
> Output written on mainfile.pdf (1 page, 25806 bytes).
145a154
>
```

Full log file of the laptop compilation:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.9.2)  1 NOV 2022 14:21
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**mainfile.tex
(./mainfile.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/doublestroke/dsfont.sty
Package: dsfont 1995/08/01 v0.1 Double stroke roman fonts
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty
Package: mathrsfs 1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk)
\symrsfs=\mathgroup4
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty
Package: latexsym 1998/08/17 v2.2e Standard LaTeX package (lasy symbols)
\symlasy=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lasy' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/lasy/m/n --> U/lasy/b/n on input line 52.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\symAMSa=\mathgroup6
\symAMSb=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stmaryrd/stmaryrd.sty
Package: stmaryrd 1994/03/03 St Mary's Road symbol package
\symstmry=\mathgroup8
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `stmry' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/stmry/m/n --> U/stmry/b/n on input line 89.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esvect/esvect.sty
Package: esvect 
\symesvector=\mathgroup9
)
\symmcy=\mathgroup10
\symmathx=\mathgroup11
Now handling font encoding LS2 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LS2
\symarrows3=\mathgroup12
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-02-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
)
(./mainfile.aux)
\openout1 = `mainfile.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LS2/stix/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for LS2+stix on input line 29.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix/ls2stix.fd
File: ls2stix.fd 2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX LS2 font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+rsfs on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd
File: ursfs.fd 1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+lasy on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd
File: ulasy.fd 1998/08/17 v2.2e LaTeX symbol font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+stmry on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stmaryrd/Ustmry.fd)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+esvect on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esvect/uesvect.fd
File: uesvect.fd 
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for LS2+stixtt on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix/ls2stixtt.fd
File: ls2stixtt.fd 2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX typewriter LS2 font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+dsrom on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/doublestroke/Udsrom.fd
File: Udsrom.fd 1995/08/01 v0.1 Double stroke roman font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Freeze math alphabet allocation in version normal.
(Font)              Allocated math groups: 14 (local: 2) on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+euf on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/ueuf.fd
File: ueuf.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 Euler Fraktur
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input line 31.

Overfull \hbox (14.37418pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 30--35
$\U/dsrom/m/n/10 1\U/euf/m/n/10 f$ \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Tex
t-Text-Text Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text Text-
 []

LaTeX Font Info:    No math alphabet change to frozen version normal on input line 35.
[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./mainfile.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1471 strings out of 478268
 22894 string characters out of 5846348
 298945 words of memory out of 5000000
 19674 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 476823 words of font info for 63 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,5n,51p,178b,107s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/doublestr
oke/dsrom10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/euler/eufm10.pfb>
Output written on mainfile.pdf (1 page, 25806 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 28 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 16 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Full Overleaf log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.8.9)  1 NOV 2022 13:22
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-05> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/doublestroke/dsfont.sty
Package: dsfont 1995/08/01 v0.1 Double stroke roman fonts
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty
Package: mathrsfs 1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk)
\symrsfs=\mathgroup4
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty
Package: latexsym 1998/08/17 v2.2e Standard LaTeX package (lasy symbols)
\symlasy=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lasy' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/lasy/m/n --> U/lasy/b/n on input line 52.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\symAMSa=\mathgroup6
\symAMSb=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stmaryrd/stmaryrd.sty
Package: stmaryrd 1994/03/03 St Mary's Road symbol package
\symstmry=\mathgroup8
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `stmry' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/stmry/m/n --> U/stmry/b/n on input line 89.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esvect/esvect.sty
Package: esvect 
\symesvector=\mathgroup9
)
\symmcy=\mathgroup10
\symmathx=\mathgroup11
Now handling font encoding LS2 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LS2
\symarrows3=\mathgroup12
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-08-05 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
) (./output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LS2/stix/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for LS2+stix on input line 29.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix/ls2stix.fd
File: ls2stix.fd 2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX LS2 font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+rsfs on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd
File: ursfs.fd 1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+lasy on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd
File: ulasy.fd 1998/08/17 v2.2e LaTeX symbol font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+stmry on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stmaryrd/Ustmry.fd)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+esvect on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esvect/uesvect.fd
File: uesvect.fd 
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for LS2+stixtt on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix/ls2stixtt.fd
File: ls2stixtt.fd 2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX typewriter LS2 font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+dsrom on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/doublestroke/Udsrom.fd
File: Udsrom.fd 1995/08/01 v0.1 Double stroke roman font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Freeze math alphabet allocation in version normal.
(Font)              Allocated math groups: 14 (local: 2) on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+euf on input line 31.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/ueuf.fd
File: ueuf.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 Euler Fraktur
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Undo math alphabet allocation in version normal on input line 31.

Overfull \hbox (14.37418pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 30--35
$\U/dsrom/m/n/10 1\U/euf/m/n/10 f$ \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text-Text Text-
 []

LaTeX Font Info:    No math alphabet change to frozen version normal on input line 35.
[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./output.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1494 strings out of 477678
 23551 string characters out of 5829488
 309332 words of memory out of 5000000
 20286 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 476823 words of font info for 63 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,5n,51p,174b,107s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/doublestroke/dsrom10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/euler/eufm10.pfb>
Output written on output.pdf (1 page, 25795 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 28 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 16 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: compare the log-files of the two compilations.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : thanks, I did have a look at the log files (which I now copied above), but I do not know how to read them/what to conclude. Actually, even using the 2021 TeX distribution on Overleaf produced a "correct" result without the strange space.

Comment: well your laptop has an older LaTeX, but I can't test this combination. Try what happens if you replace the `$$(P)$$` by the proper `\[(P)\]`. Or update your tex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : thank you so much! You made a correct guess: using `\[` instead of `$$` made everything fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$` resolved my problem.