# Too many math alphabets used in version normal error when using chemmacros package

Tags: errors, chemmacros

When I load package `chemmacros`, suddenly the following error occurs:

```
Too many math alphabets used in version normal.
```

I've already made sure that I've updated my MikTeX distribution.

Edit: my code is

```
\documentclass[english,fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,BCOR=5mm,footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
% Classic Thesis Style loader
\makeatother
\input{classicthesis-config.tex}
\makeatletter
% use Latin Modern instead of Computer Modern sans serif
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[minionint]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\[
-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m_{e}}\underset{i}{\sum}\nabla_{i}^{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

, whereby the "classicthesis-config.tex" is the same one as the one in https://code.google.com/p/classicthesis (LyX version).

What should I do to repair this problem?

By the way, if I replace the `\hbar` with `\alpha`, the problem disappears. The problem still remains if I replace `\hbar` with `\hslash`.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: At least related: [“Too many math alphabets” error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3676/too-many-math-alphabets-error)

Comment: Your exampel produces  `! LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.`

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake when copying the code to the forum. I've edited the code. I also add more description there.

Comment: The problem is almost surely in the `MinionPro` package that's not generally available.

Comment: For short example here, disabling `MinionPro` helps, but for the actual document that I'm writing, where there are a lot of equations, the error still pop out. And strangely I get another error, such as the one in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101467/support-package-expl3-too-old-when-using-siunitx when compiling in another computer (with MinionPro package). Hmm, for now I just use regular `\textsubscript{}` instead of using `chemmacros` package. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: @user26939 I'm having the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?