# Mathtime and (unwanted) bold version of \mathcal

Tags: bold, mathcal, mathtime

I have mathtime (not the new fancy MTPro2, but rather, the version from the early 1990's).  I learned this summer how to use
\DeclareMathVersion so that I could have some chapters in my document that load their fonts separately.  (This helps us to overcome the 16 font maximum.)  The original question was posted online here:
[LaTeX: Using attributes of one mathversion with another mathversion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497640/)

Question:  When I use \DeclareMathVersion to make "normal2", I find that the \mathcal font shows up in bold, and I do not want it to be bold.  How can I get \mathcal to show up without being bold?  Here is my MWE.  Thank you (in advance) for your help.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtime}

\DeclareMathVersion{normal2}
\makeatletter
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {normal2}{\operator@encoding}{ptm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {normal2}{MY1}{mtt}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {normal2}{MY2}{mtt}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal2}{MY3}{mtt}{m}{n}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$(a=b)$  $\mathcal{ABC}$  % \mathcal is not bold -- good!

\mathversion{normal2}
$(a=b)$  $\mathcal{ABC}$  % \mathcal is bold, why?
                          % I just want the regular (not bold) \mathcal here!
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have the fonts any more, but are you sure it's bold rather than just darker than the default family? if you add `\showoutput` what log do you get for the two ABC, the standard one will be `.....\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 C` what does the mathtime one say?

Comment: I only asked for one line:-)

Comment: so `.\OMS/cmsy/b/n/12 A `  so you are getting bold cm mathcal not mathtime at all

Comment: looks like the good ones are:
.....\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 A
.....\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 B
.....\kern0.36494
.....\OMS/cmsy/m/n/12 C

and the undesirable ones are:
.....\OMS/cmsy/b/n/12 A
.....\OMS/cmsy/b/n/12 B
.....\kern0.27011
.....\OMS/cmsy/b/n/12 C

Comment: Solved!  I added this line to mathversion "normal2" and I am all set now!   \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
Thank you very much @DavidCarlisle!!

Comment: sure that's what I put in the first comment:-)

Answer (score 3):

The comments in `mathtime.sty` go in at great length about `\mathcal` basically Frank and I saying **It's not our fault**

basically you are seeing the effect of

```
\ifx\mathcal c
  \let\mathcal\relax
  \DeclareMathAlphabet\mathcal{OMS}        {cmsy}{b}{n}
  \SetMathAlphabet    \mathcal{normal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
```

that means you get bold cm mathcal in every version except `normal`.

Perhaps you want to add after loading `mathtime`

```
  \SetMathAlphabet    \mathcal{normal2}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  Thank you very much @David Carlisle!!  :)

Comment: Wow, I am talking to a famous guy!  I did not notice the copyright line in mathtime.sty   which says "Copyright 1996 1997 Frank Mittelbach and David Carlisle."!

Comment: One more question while I am bugging you:  I see 5 "if" conditions (including the one that you mentioned) in my mathtime.sty.  In anticipation of other unintended consequences from \DeclareMathVersion, should I add any other lines to "normal2"?  This was a subtle difference that I found (regular versus bold), and I would be hesitant to miss other differences, when I am using \DeclareMathVersion.  Any other similar advice for me?  (I am sincerely thankful for your help!)

Comment: @mdw they are implementing the other options for mathcal as explained in the comments. No option is really that great as better would be a designed caligraphic to go with mathtime but that wasn't available. But adding that line over-writes whatever the package does so you win there in any case.

Comment: (you might be better these days using stix, or using it for mathcal that is a far more complete times-like math font collelection (and free)