# Use newtx only to have its scribe letters in mathmode

Tags: fonts, pdftex, math-fonts

I would like to use newtx onl to have its scribe letters in mathmode and "double letters" like for real numbers but in minuscule version. Default LaTeX font (CMU) should be preserved. Specifications of my problem are:

1. I use pdfLaTeX
2. I really don't know how to handle fonts in it

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but the question is a bit too vague.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question right, you want to load the calligraphic math fonts `\mathcal` and black board bold math fonts `\mathbb` from `txfonts`, while using Computer Modern for everything else in the document. This situation is *exactly* what the [mathalpha](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha?lang=en) package is designed for.

In your case, you should be able to accomplish what you want with

```
\usepackage[cal=pxtx,bb=tx]{mathalpha}
```

---

If you want to just load the `txfonts` double-struck and calligraphic letters *in addition to* Computer Modern, you can do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcaltx}{U}{tx-cal}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbtx}{OT1}{tx-ds}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
$\mathbbtx{ABCabc} = \mathbb{ABC}$

$\mathcaltx{ABC} = \mathcal{ABC}$
\end{document}
```

Be aware however that TeX has [a limit to how many math alphabets you can use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3676/too-many-math-alphabets-error).

Comment: Well, I admit my question might be inaccurate, but you've given me something I can use, but I still miss lowercase letters in caligraphics and double letters. Ideally I would like to use this font only on certain parts of equation like left hand side in newtx, right hand side in CMU.

Comment: `bb=tx` should give you lower case blackboard bold. The txfonts do not have lower calligraphic letters to my knowledge; comparatively few math fonts do. // Your final sentence is unclear: (1) do you mean that you want to use the CM `\mathcal` alongside that of txfonts? (2) Computer Modern does not have blackboard bold; frequently with CM or Latin Modern people would load the `amssymb` version of `\mathbb`.

Comment: First one - I want to use CM \mathcal alongside that of txfonts. Thanks!